# Copy email address from one input form to another—different pages

Tags: email, inputbox

I am making a website with a place to type in an email address to sign up for a mailing list. Once GO has been pressed, another page shows up with another email input and another GO button.

Is it possible to somehow grab the first email address after it's been typed and automatically place it into the second page's email box?

My code for the first email box:

```
<div id="email">
<form action="http://widget-platform.fanbridge.com/widget/render/12676" target="blank" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="1"><div align="left">

                    </div></td>

                        <td valign="top"><div align="right"></div></td>
                        <td valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>


                    <td > 
                        <div class="img"><input type="image" img src="img/go.png" /></td></span>
                        </div>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>                  

      </div>
```

Comment: The answer to this question strongly depends on whether you are to use PHP (server/host-side), JavaScript (user/client-side), ... or whatever language you prefer.

Comment: I would probably use javascript as i'm not too familiar with php

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a JavaScript-function that retrieves the value from the first input-box and copies it to the second:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function copyMail(f) {
    f.secondInputMail.value = f.firstInputMail.value;
}
</script>
```

The submit-"button" then needs to be added an attribute `onClick` to call this function:

```
<input type="image" img src="img/go.png" onClick="copyMail(this.form);" />
```

It jas been a while since I used JavaScript, but you should get an idea from this.